# My 1-3 month old bearded dragon ate bark

Tags: reptiles, bearded-dragon

So uh, my bearded dragon Qibli is around 3 months old. I have a peace of tree limb in there and he loves to climb on it. A small part of the bark came off (aspin tree bark) and he kinda just ate it..? I don't know if this is going to affect him at all but I'm kinda scared- I don't know what to do :(